# SharePoint Error Page "Sorry, something went wrong" with Correlation ID: 6f8cbc9c-a65f-c067-e92a-0df249a1880e

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions, user-profile

I created a new site on SharePoint 2013 and I published this.

I can see the websites on the server which has sharepoint normally.

Another users opens the site on their computer, but user to do anything get the error following.

[image]

The correct the error I refresh the page on the server which has SharePoint. And then the problem solves. But the error can repeat another time.

Is there a permanent solution not to refresh on the page every time.Can you help  me please?

Thanks.

Comment: The correlation id is not really any help for troubleshooting this error for us. You should search the ULS logs for this correlation is to get more details about the error. Post those details here and we might be able to help you out

Comment: I looked my logs in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS. But I didn't undestand this. What should I look in this log? @RobertLindgren

Comment: @RobertLindgren   
I looked my logs in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS. But I didn't undestand this. What should I look in this log?

Comment: Search for the correlation number (GUID) in the file for the time when you got the error. You should find more details about the error that occurred

Comment: Thanks for help @RobertLindgren. I looked logs and I found this:  
Warning  Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  
Users or services are accessing the site http://kuhaz with the URL http://kuh.  
This may cause incorrect links to be stored or returned to users.  
If this is expected, add the URL http://kuh as an AAM response URL.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I solved this problem with this url :  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208(v=office.15).aspx